# Remove heavy folders from push

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have 6 commits ahead from remote master.
One folder is full of high res pictures and was commited 5 commits before.
I can't push because the changes are too heavy.

Problem: even if I remove the dir from the history, plus adding it to gitignore, my push to master is still the same size and failes.
At 97% it starts to grow from 20mb to 500

Any other way of cleaning it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to rebase your local commits and remove the heavy folder:

```
git rebase --interactive COMMIT_THAT_ADDED_THE_FOLDER^ # the ^ is important here
# change 'pick' to 'edit' on the line for the commit that added
#       the folder (should be the first one), then validate
git rm --cached -r THE_FOLDER # it will remove the folder but keep it locally
git rebase --continue
# you may encounter conflict if you modified files in the folder in next commits
```

You should consider using solution like [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to handle heavy files in git repository.